# spo.optimize :only integers, slices (:), ellipsis (...), numpy.newaxis (None) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

```
df = pd.read_csv("loc.csv",index_col=['Date'],na_values=['NA'],
                     parse_dates=True)

dates = pd.date_range('2010-01-01','2010-12-31')

symbols = ['AAPL','GOOG']

df1= df.ix[dates,symbols]

df1=df1.dropna(how='all')

line = [.5,0]

def min1 (df1,l ):
    err= np.sum( (df1['GOOG']-(df1['AAPL']*l[0]+l[1]))**2 )
    return err
```

result = spo.minimize (min1 , line, args= (df1), method = 'SLSQP' ,options ={'disp':True } )

I am getting an error as below :

```
only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The error means that some variable which is a float or array (or list) is being used in an indexing role; i.e. somewhere it shouldn't be.

While I'd have to study it your code more carefully, the first thing that catches my eye is the `(df)`.  This should be tuple, and needs a comma:

```
args= (df1,)
```

If that simple fix doesn't work, give more of the error stack, so we have a better idea of where the problem is occurring.

---

Does this run?

```
min1(line, df1)
```

The first argument for the function is the 'free variable', the one that `minimize` is varying, starting the the `x0` value (`line`).  The `args` parameter provides added arguments, when don't vary.

---

Given the initial value, `line = [.5,0]`, `min1` is actually called (the first time with

```
min1(np.array([.5,0]), df1)
```

But inside `min1` you index the first argument with a string, as though it were a Pandas object, not a simple 2 element array

```
df1['GOOG']  # here df1 is the initial array, not the dataframe
```

That may be what's producing the error.

So the root of the problem is a confusion as the order of arguments to `min1`, and mixing up arrays and dataframes.

Comment: thanks for the reply ..min1(line, df1).. this worked ....in the function 'l' is a 2 element series and df1 is a panda.....I am not clear about your comment "mixing up arrays and dataframes."  pls explain